# Not able to open Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am getting this error while opening visualforce page :

> The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF
>   confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce
>   administrator.

This is VF code. What can be the issue ?

```
<apex:page  sidebar="true" showHeader="true" >
</apex:page>
```

Comment: <apex:page  sidebar="true" showHeader="true" >

</apex:page>

Comment: is that your complete vf page code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

believe you have enabled the **Require CSRF protection on GET requests** checkbox on the page.

if you uncheck this checkbox then the page should load fine.

Go to Setup -> Develop -> Pages -> select your page and edit it to remove this checkbox.

[image]

you can refer these salesforce articles for additional information on when and why this checkbox is used.

[Defining Visualforce Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_creating.htm)

[Secure Coding Cross Site Request Forgery](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Request_Forgery)

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing the following error:

"**The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce administrator.**"

This is because the Visualforce Page you are navigating to has the metadata checkbox turned on:
true

If you are looking to get your App Security Reviewed, you will need to enable these tokens for each Visualforce page you are navigating to through a web link.

We had a bit of a different pattern:
Our weblinks were created as on click javascript
To solve this, we have changed the  for all the web links that were "on click javascript" to:
url

Then in the  body we ensure we are generating "well-formed URLs" using URLFOR.